# Vue.js component isn't updated after parent changes boud data field

Tags: vue.js

I have roughly the following:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <h1>Toolbox</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <Info :file_data="file_data" v-if="file_loaded"/>
    <DropArea @file-dropped="onDrop"/>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import DropArea from './components/DropArea.vue'
import Info from './components/Info.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Toolbox',
  components: {
    DropArea,
    Info,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file_loaded: false,
      reader: new FileReader(),
      file_data: new Uint8Array(),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onDrop(file) {    
      this.reader.onloadend =this.onFileLoaded;
      this.reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    },
    onFileLoaded(file_data) {
      this.file_loaded = true
      this.file_data = new Uint8Array(this.reader.result); //this should update the property on the Info Component
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The Info Component uses a property and watches it like this:

```
<script>
export default {
name: 'Info',
props: ['file_data'],
watch: {
    file_data: 'onFileDataChanged'
},
methods: {
    onFileDataChanged() {
        console.log('file_data changed')
    }
},
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for the first dropped file. Only from the second file onwards, it works. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thx
Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, watchers only watch on updates to the value. To have it call on the initial value as well, set `immediate: true` with the object syntax.

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#watch)

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Info',
  props: ['file_data'],
  watch: {
    file_data: {
      handler: 'onFileDataChanged',
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
   onFileDataChanged() {
      console.log('file_data changed')
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [depth](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) prop is what you need to tackle with:

`watch: { file_data: { handler: 'onFileDataChanged', deep: true } }`